# How to one hot encode multiple columns in CSV file using sklearn?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, data-science

I have the following code for One hot encoding one column in my CSV file.

```
from sklearn.compose import ColumnTransformer
from sklearn.preprocessing import OneHotEncoder
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0])], remainder='passthrough')
X = np.array(ct.fit_transform(X))
```

Now I want to one hot encode more than one columns in that CSV file by using only index number and not name of that column, how can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, the third argument of the transformers=[] is the list of indexes of columns to one hot encode. So for example, if you wanted to one hot encode both columns indexed 0 and 1, your third line might look like this:

```
ct = ColumnTransformer(transformers=[('encoder', OneHotEncoder(), [0,1])], remainder='passthrough')
```

I found this link helpful: https://machinelearningmastery.com/columntransformer-for-numerical-and-categorical-data/